# bash FUNCNAME value expanding

Tags: bash

I have one lib-file. It has one wrapper-like substitution of `ponOS` function. I want to display in function ponOS name of function where it is called from.

```
$> cat ./parasha_lib.sh 
#!/bin/bash

function ponOS {
    echo "$1: hello from ponOS"
}

ponOS='ponOS ${FUNCNAME}'
```

But, what I see is that this solution did not work as well as I want.

```
$> cat ./test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

source ./parasha_lib.sh

function main {
    echo "message from ${FUNCNAME}"
    ponOS
}

main
```

So, I've got

```
$> ./test.sh 
message from main
: hello from ponOS
```

But I wanna get this:

```
$> ./test.sh 
message from main
main: hello from ponOS
```

What should I do?

One of the important things here is that ./test.sh shouldn't be modified (ponOS ${FUNCNAME} it's not the solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that, you need to set `ponOS` as an alias so that `${FUNCNAME}` is expanded when called within the main function and not when the script is sourced.

Modify `./parasha_lib.sh`  to:

```
#!/bin/bash

function ponOS {
    echo "$1: hello from ponOS"
}

shopt -s expand_aliases           # enable alias expansion
alias ponOS='ponOS ${FUNCNAME}'   # create an alias to call ponOS
```

Note that `shopt -s expand_aliases` is required to enable alias expansion. From the bash manpage:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt

Now, without changing `test.sh` we get the desired output:

```
[me@home]$ ./test.sh
message from main
main: hello from ponOS
```

Answer (score 1):

See FUNCNAME at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables

## parasha_lib.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function ponOS {
    echo "${FUNCNAME[1]}: hello from ponOS"
}
```

## test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./parasha_lib.sh

function main {
    echo "message from ${FUNCNAME}"
    ponOS
}

main
```

## Result ./test.sh

```
message from main
main: hello from ponOS
```